# Polymer 2 data repository singleton

Tags: polymer, polymer-2.x

I would like to implement a single data respository that is available to many of my view elements. My first idea was to simply create a plain JS object and add it to the global namespace (optionally adding a custom namespace).

But then I would loose the possibility to easily import elements like, f.e., iron-ajax. So I thought it would be better to define the repository as a Polymer element.

Now the question is whether the views should access the singleton via the global instance or should I have a wrapper element that the views would instantiate declaratively which itself is a facade to the global instance. In both cases it is not fully clear to me how to instantiate the global instance (document.createElement maybe?)

My data repository will provide methods like getData, getDevices etc. that should be accessible by all views. Some of these methods will cache static data others will have parameters and load different data with every call.

Is there any recommended pattern to this?

Comment: Have you looked into redux? There was a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PahsgJn0sgU) about using it with Polymer.

Comment: Thanks, I will definitely have a look at it. Before writing this post I studied this nice article https://www.captaincodeman.com/2017/07/06/managing-state-in-polymer-20-beyond-parent-child-binding and thought I could get around using redux. The problem is that my case is a little different. I want a singleton with an API accessible by views and don't care too much about change notifications (at this moment) which is the main focus of the article.